# How to export all users with all custom fields?

Tags: 7, users, entities, importing-exporting

I want to export users list with all custom fields. I have tried the [Users Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/users_export) module but its export only below fields:

- uid
- mail
- name
- created
- access
- login

Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Drush Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_entity) module:

> With drush entity you can query the entity system available for Drupal
>   8, 7 and (some of) 6.

**Getting all users with some fields:**

```
drush entity-read user `drush entity-read user` --fields=uid,mail,name,created,access,login
```

**Getting one user with all the fields:**

```
drush entity-read user 1 --fields=* --format=json
```

**Getting all the users with all the fields:**

```
drush entity-read user `drush entity-read user` --fields=*
```

**Getting some users with some fields:**

```
drush entity-read user 1 2 --fields=uid,mail,name,created,access,login --format=export
```

**Output (for the last command):**

```
 1  mail@gmail.com  admin  1353518169  1470089957  1469713365
 2  other@gmail.com  webadmin  1353518169  1470089957  1469713365
```

If you want to try with another options you can read this page: http://build2be.com/content/drush-entity-support-patch-needs-review

Comment: So what is it that you do not use Drush for these days?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I'm studying Drush in these days, I think is very powerful for make scripts to process a lot of data and for get quickly information of your site.

Comment: Drush is indeed amazing! And it'll be interesting to see how it is going evolve as compared to the "Console" in D8 ...

Answer (score 1):

There are many option to achieve this.

You can create a user view and use [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module for export.

Another option to achieve this is [Data export import](https://www.drupal.org/project/data_export_import) module.

Comment: Data export import module export the user but still custom field are not showing. I also want the user export in csv file. Any idea?

Comment: How you create the custom fields?

Comment: Yes you can export user list in csv file using "Views data export" module.

Comment: Thank you. Now I am able to export data in csv file with  Views data export module. There is an option for Batched export which helps to  export data in small segments but it is not working.

Comment: Also I want to add the checkbox in user list to export the selected users. Any idea?

Comment: Are you able to export all user fields data?

Comment: Yes I am able to export all user list at once.

Answer (score 1):

## Start from a Forena's sample report (Active users)

Install the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of it) and start from the "Active Users" report (part of ***Drupal Administration*** report category) which is delivered with it. Here is a sample output of it:

```
+-----------+-----------------------+-------------------------+---------+
| User      | Email                 | Last Logged in          | Actions |
+-----------+-----------------------+-------------------------+---------+
| Webmaster | webmaster@example.com | Sun, 03/27/2016 - 18:39 | logs    |
| Admin     | info@example.com      | Thu, 04/07/2016 - 12:47 | logs    |
| Pierre    | pierre@example.com    | Fri, 04/01/2016 - 18:19 | logs    |
+-----------+-----------------------+-------------------------+---------+
```

## Refine the delivered report

Next, just customize this reports, or create a clone from it that fits your needs. For example by using the query writing tool that comes with Forena, which is called the **Forena Query Builder**. This is a separated (sub-)module which can be enabled as per standard Drupal instructions to enable an additional module. For a video tutorial about this query writing tool, checkout [Define data blocks with optional filters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPdFftH4CGs). Add any of the "*custom fields*" (as in your question) you want.

## Set the report's export options

For the report you create, set the appropriate "document types" that fit your needs. Such as CSV, XLS, PDF, XLS, etc. For those document types you enable, an authorized report user will be able to click a hyperlink to export the report (in this case the list of users with the custom fields you added), in any of the formats you enabled within document types. Should you rather want JSON or XML format (as export format), that is also possible (just a slightly different approach, which is typically restricted to selected user roles only).